# Is there any method to create profile for PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, profiles, ghostdriver

For firefox using Selenium, we can create profiles similar to this:

> [How to create profile in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269570/how-to-create-profile-in-firefox-using-selenium-web-driver)
>   https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Also we have the list of attributes we can set in the profile here (Tor project reference)

https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/tree/browser/app/profile/000-tor-browser.js?h=tor-browser-31.6.0esr-4.5-1

Is there a similar way to get profile created for PhantomJS for all the attributes listed in above? Is it really possible to set all attributes for PhantomJS? or PhantomJS supports only limited set.

Thanks,
Hareesh

Comment: u can look in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868957/how-do-you-create-a-browser-profile-for-seleniums-phantomjs-ghostdriver

Comment: @noor: I have already pasted this link in my question. My question was to know about equivalent ways in PhantomJS for the above mentioned firefox profile.

Comment: your link and my given link are not same .... pls check it properly

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with a "profile" (there isn't one for PhantomJS)?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for responding It's to replicate the same what TOR browser does in PhantomJS. Since Tor browsers takes too much time to start and also a heavy weight program, trying to test with PhantomJS if the same is feasible so that it would be a lightweight program.

Comment: @noor Oh sorry, but I have already seen this link. But that link still doesn't provide equivalent for PhantomJS. It only shows few attributes that can be used in FF

Comment: Since there is no profile equivalent to Firefox, why don't you edit your question to ask your actual question of how to use PhantomJS with TOR? Always be aware of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266187).