# How to save and reuse a Firefox profile to disk after creating it with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automation

I am doing web-scraping with selenium/geckodriver on windows machine.
My create_driver function defines a specific Firefox profile:

```
def create_driver()
    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()                        # Disable CSS
    firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2) # Disable images
    firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)      # Disable Flash
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)         # Create driver
    return driver

driver = create_driver()
```

However, for every run Firefox creates a new, 400 KB profile file in `C:/User/Appdata/Local/temp` (tmpaddon-xxxxxx, see picture below):

This obviously creates significant overhead that I need to get rid of.
I know that profiles can be created manually using [Firefox Profile Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). Those can then be used with selenium like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47748234/6060083). However, I did not figure out yet how to create & populate those profile files using python.

**Q1: How to save and reuse one Firefox profile with specs that have been defined in python to disk?**

**Q2: How to prevent Firefox from auto-saving a profile once every driver instance runs?**

[image: Firefox profile files]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/path/profile.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: which leavers the question on how to edit the '/path/profile.default' file

Comment: Why can't you use  the Firefox Profile Manager?

Comment: my scraper is written in python - therefore the process of creating and storing a profile should ideally be accomplished in python as well - what I just did is to let firefox create it in the temp folder, then rename and relocate it - this works. However, the temp files mentioned above are still created for every iteration

Comment: @sudonym Perhaps I didn't understand the situation but I thought that if you call the driver providing an existing, manually generated profile(like I suggested) instead of creating a clean Webdriver instance(like in your question), it will not create an additional profile file and just reuse the one you provided instead. Isn't that the case?

Comment: According to my current understanding/observation this is not the case unfortunately. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40527704/6060083 - The thing is that this is an IO/Disc operation which slows things down - not ideal. If you have suggestions on how I should edit the title of this question in order for people to better undertstand, feel free. Sorry for my non-precision here